# Error Timeout 504 GET Request JSON cURL PHP with HTTPheader

Tags: php, json, api, curl

I have a PHP script to request JSON data with cURL, PHP and HTTPheader, before it worked but suddenly it is not working, and I got `Gateway Timeout 504`.
This PHP script run from Linux VPS Hosting, with specs:

- OS Debian 11,
- Apache/2.4.54 (Debian)
- mod_fcgid/2.3.9
- OpenSSL/1.1.1n
- PHP Version 7.4.30.
- curl 7.74.0

And this is my code:

```
<?php
    $consid    = "my_id";
    $secretKey = "my_secretkey";
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    $tStamp = strval(time()-strtotime('1970-01-01 00:00:00'));
    $signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $consid."&".$tStamp, $secretKey, true);
    $encodedSignature = base64_encode($signature); 
    $ch = curl_init();
    $headers = array(
        'X-cons-id: '.$consid.'',
        'X-timestamp: '.$tStamp.'',
        'X-signature: '.$encodedSignature.'',
        'Content-Type: Application/JSON',
        'Accept: Application/JSON'
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://domain.tld/aplicaresws/rest/bed/ref/kelas");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1');
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    $err = curl_error($ch);
    $data = json_decode($content,true);
    foreach ($data["response"] as $record) {}
    $data2 = array( 'data'  => $record );
    $data3 = json_encode($data2);
    $fp = fopen("bedlist.json", "w");
    fwrite($fp, $data3);
    fclose($fp);
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Please help review my script what's wrong with this curl PHP code?

Comment: That error is not from your script but from the remote side. Inspect there. In particular, you don't provide the info to reproduce it. Also, if the code worked before and doesn't now, it's probably not in that code, right?

Comment: Your servers may be misconfigured

Comment: maybe yes, misconfigured on the server, because when i try this script on another server with Ubuntu 20.04, its run well and got response. i'll check it out